# NotificationHub Register issue at IOS (React Native)

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to register **notificationHub** from React Native. I created a **NativeModule** and I'm sending **connectionString**, **hubName**, **tags** and **deviceToken** - deviceToken was saved to **AsyncStorage** (I'm getting deviceToken before user logged and I can't register Notification Hub without user tag (ex: scholarshipID) so I'm saving deviceToken for later usage. Because I can't send user tags to `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` from RN )

After user login I'm getting user scholarshipID & deviceToken and sending to native module for NotificationHub register.

```
 // deviceToken:(NSString *)tokenForLaterUsage

 [hub
   registerNativeWithDeviceToken:tokenForLaterUsage
   tags:self->_tags
   completion:^(NSError* error)
   {
     if (error != nil) {
       NSLog(@"Error registering for notifications: %@", error);
     }else{
       NSLog(@"Success");
     }
   }];
```

My **tokenForLaterUsage** is string and if I try use directly app is crashing. Because **NotificationHub** register function is waiting **NSData** so I'm  converting **NSString** to **NSData** like this way:

```
    NSData* data = [tokenForLaterUsage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

After this I'm going Azure Portal and trying to send notification but system saying no device found.

BTW : When I try to register to NotificationHub in here: `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` **it's work well** but I can't set tags so this is not for me. From here I'm just getting deviceToken for later usage.

--

*note: I'm thinking 2 workaround to solve this issue (But I'm not sure if works.):*

1. *Workaround*: I don't know but if I can I'll not register at first and when user will be login I'll get deviceToken on IOS and I'll try to register to NotificationHub.
2. *Workaround*: I'll send my deviceToken to directly backend with restApi and backEnd will pair user tags and deviceToken.

*Sorry things mixed but I need to solve this. Also sorry for my English :).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.

At first when **deviceToken** is generated I'm storing at **NSUserDefaults**

```
NSUserDefaults *userPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userPreferences setObject:deviceToken forKey:@"deviceToken"];
[userPreferences synchronize];
```

And when user login I'm getting the deviceToken from NSUserDefault in NativeModules and sending to NotificationHub.

```
NSData *token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"deviceToken"];
```